# Embedding Strobe Media Playback into .NET C# application

Tags: c#, .net, flash, rtmp

I was trying to capture RTMP stream in C# application and play it.

I've chosen the following architecture:

1. Embed Flash Player into C# app. (done)
2. Run Strobe Media Playback in embedded Flash Player. (done)
3. Capture RTMP stream in embedded Strobe Media Playback player. (failed)

The problem is that I cannot set the video source location. Neither RTMP nor HTTP sources work.
Strobe Media Playback displays the only text string: "We are unable to connect to the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience."

I have tried several ways to set the source:

1. Through setting FlashVars:
   `flash.FlashVars = @"src=http://players.edgesuite.net/videos/big_buck_bunny/bbb_448x252.mp4";`
   or 
   `flash.FlashVars = @"FlashVars=""src=http://players.edgesuite.net/videos/big_buck_bunny/bbb_448x252.mp4""";`
2. Through creating XML-config and passing info about it to Strobe by means of FlashVars:
   `flash.FlashVars = @"configuration=D:\configuration.xml";`

Also I'm unable to play locally hosted .flv-files any of this ways.

Is it theoretically possible what I'm trying to do?

If it is, how can I set the video source for Strobe Playback from C# code?

*Additional technical info:*

*For embedding Flash Player into C# app I use two libraries:*
*AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll*

*Flash version: 11.5.502.135*
*Strobe Media Playback version: 1.6.328*

*Sample C# project can be found here:*
http://narod.ru/disk/64598707001.c8d1ae94c60a63a021bfdffc82864bb2/WPF_Flash.7z.html

P.S. If you know better ways to capture and play RTMP stream in .NET application, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`parameters.flashvars="src=rtmp:[url here]`

Comment: I've achieved the result by placing browser window onto the WPF-window. Then I've embedded the strobe player into dynamically generated page with parameters inside html-attribute.

Comment: Your solution seems to be cleaner, so if it works, it should be preferred. But anyway combining WPF and Flash is not the best choice for a production environment.